# How to make resizeable box go from left to bottom as well as right to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok, so I am working on building my own catalogue of some sort.  I am working on making a selecting tool to choose a part of the image to see up close.  [This is where I am currently working on it](http://levijackson.net/projects/catalogue/)

Anyway, I am missing something in my logic as far as how to make the box resize when I drag from the bottom right corner to the top left.  I know it isn't working because of how the box is positioned.  Positioning works by using the top left corner as a reference point.  So I had two solutions I was working on but I couldn't get very far with them.

The first was trying to figure out a way to position the box based on the bottom right corner.

The other method I was playing with was perhaps offsetting the box position by the height/width and perhaps this would have the effect of having a bottom right position.

[This is a quick link to my JS](http://levijackson.net/projects/catalogue/common/script.js)

So, any help with working through this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it somewhat. Basically you want to draw a box from (top,left) to (bottom,right). Assuming:

- (downX,downY): coordinates when you press the moust;
- (currentX,currentY): current coordinates.

then:

- top: min(downY,currentY);
- left: min(downX,currentX);
- bottom: max(downY,currentY);
- right: max(downX,currentX).

What you're doing with calculating if it's left to right or right to left seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: That does clear my code up quite a bit.  What I don't get from your example is how to size the draggable box. (I am probably missing it though)  I keep running into the ability to only drag top left to bottom right.  I want to be able to drag bottom right to top left as well though.